# jQuery: this = $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I wanted to create a jQuery plugin that would determine if an element is of a particular class OR a parent is of a particular class.

---

## Example

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="root">
     <div id="a" class="myClass">
          <div id="b"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I would expect the following results:

```
>$('#a').isOrParent('.myClass');
 true
>$('#b').isOrParent('.myClass');
 true
>$('#root').isOrParent('.myClass');
 false
```

---

### Solution A (works)

```
$.fn.isOrParent = function (selector) {
    this = $(this);
    if (this.is(selector))
        return true;
    if (this.parents(selector).length !== 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

### Solution B (does not work)

```
$.fn.isOrParent = function (selector) {
    $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(selector))
        return true;
    if ($this.parents(selector).length !== 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

### Solution C (does not work)

```
$.fn.isOrParent = function (selector) {
    if (this.is(selector))
        return true;
    if (this.parents(selector).length !== 0)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

---

## Question

Solution A works however is throwing the following exception in Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

Because of this error, I attempted Solution B and C unsuccessfully.

This raises the following questions:

- Why does Solution A work if there is an exception?
- Why does Solution B not work?

Comment: `this` is a special keyword... you cannot assign a value to it

Comment: I know that, it was more of an accident. The fact that it worked boggles me though.

Comment: inside the plugin `this` refers a jQuery wrapper object

Comment: in side jquery plugin, `this` is already a jquery object. Don't need `$(this)`

Comment: Isn't this what `closest` method does?

Comment: I think you want to take a look at `closest` it does what you want to do. and `$(this)` inside jquery proto function is unnecessary.

Comment: @KhanhTO Why does Solution C not work?

Comment: You can assign `this` to a variable and use it

Comment: solution c works http://jsfiddle.net/s2bTj/

Comment: @KhanhTO thanks for pointing that out to me. There must be something else going on in my code.

Comment: Solution b is working

Comment: A cannot "work" if it throws an error. Don't you see that not value is logged? http://jsfiddle.net/Y6Rwd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KhanhTO pointed out that Solution C does work. Turns out that the exception helped produce the anticipated results. In other words; 2 wrongs made a right.

as BlackSheep pointed out: is a better way to do this:

```
$.fn.isOrParent = function (selector) {    
  return this.closest(selector).length !== 0;
}
```